# Why can't I create a new account?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management

[Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJZqE.png) [image: Screen Shot 2]
These are the screen shots of the issue I am having.  Google please fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the image reads "That username is taken". So, you have to try using a different username.

It happens when someone has already registered an account with that username. But in your case, it is not allowed as Google has some policy on certain usernames. Best would be to try another combination.

Also see: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/3185985?hl=en